# Lagging image movements

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, window

I am experiencing a problem that I read other have experienced as well but didn't really find a solution.

While watching videos or moving windows around the view is lagging quit a few.
It becomes more obvious if there is any heavy movement happening and it happens even when I scroll some text up or down. This happens with both Gnome and Unity desktop environments.

I am currently using Ubuntu 16.04.
I am using a Nvidia GeForce GTX 1060 graphics card and I have the Nvidia proprietary driver (version 384.130) installed.

This issue showed just a few days ago.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me.

:)

Comment: I forget to mention that even the mouse pointer doesn't look quite as fluid as it normally is when moving around.